No se encuentra el punto de entrada
Hola compañeros instalé el pgAdmin4 y me muestra el siguiente error no sé por qué

pgAdmin.exe  - No se encuentra el punto de entrada
No se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento DiscardVirtualMemory en la biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin4\runtime\nw.dll



¿Que versión de Windows estas usando? Más info

La versión de nw.dll no corresponde a la versión con la que fue compilado el programa o alguna de las otras dll's que usa. El mensaje de error dice que busca una rutina que no existe en la biblioteca.

en este momento uso Windows 8

De 32 o 64 bits? y que versión de pgAdmin4 estás instalando?
